# Is it possible to respond to request from another method that the one defined in [OperationContract]?

Tags: c#, wcf

as in the title, i have:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate="abc")]
        Stream GetResponse(Stream in);
    }

    public class Service : IService
    {
        public Stream GetResponse(Stream in)
        {
           some_function()
        }   
    }
```

is it possible to pass a request context to some other function that will respond to the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, within `some_function` you can access the current WCF [`OperationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx) via [the static `Current` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.current(v=VS.100).aspx) which will give you full access to everything about the request. Or, better yet, you can design `some_function` to accept an OperationContext parameter and then it doesn't have to pull it out of thin air itself which actually makes for better testability.

In addition to the context, you will also need to take and return the `Stream` instances from `some_function` if it intends to act on them.

So your `some_function` might look something like this:

```
public Stream GetResponse(Stream in) 
{ 
    return some_function(OperationaContext.Current, in);
}
```